# directories method in Storage->('minio') return error SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, minio

i'm trying to get list of folder in my minio bucket using this code

```
public function handle()
{
    $baseDirectory = 'product/';
    $directories = Storage::disk('minio')->directories($baseDirectory);
}
```

when i run the code i got this error

> Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://some-url.id/documents?prefix=product%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET https://some-url.id/documents?prefix=product%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calcul (truncated...)
> SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. - 
> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.documents/documents/177C6CAFC2C79AD5c4b4d170-8dc4-4249-9ccc-87a889a1227c

but when i try using different method like makeDirectory, the code works just fine.

```
public function handle()
{
    // this code work just fine
    $baseDirectory = 'product/';
    $directories = Storage::disk('minio')->makeDirectory($baseDirectory);
}
```

can anyone point what is wrong with this code? i thought the problem is from my minio policy, but my current policy should be enough to use directories method
[image: minio policy]